# Mathematically same condition statements, different results

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-statements

I was trying to solve a coding problem that can be found [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/substring-concatenation/).

I tried these two definitions for my For loop

```
for(i=0;i+(num*len)-1<A.size();i++)
```

and

```
for(i=0;i<A.size()-(num*len)+1;i++)
```

Later in the code, I'm using the string.substr function to obtain substrings. For some reason, the 1st form works fine, but the second one throws the following error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
Aborted
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? I'm using C++11 with GCC 4.8.

Comment: You should do some debugging.  What is the value of `i` when this occurs?

Comment: `for(i=0;i+(num*len)-1<A.size();i++)` what is `num`? what is `len`? what is `A`?

Comment: `num` and `len` are integers. `A` is a string.

Comment: @BatCoder That seems unhelpful.

Comment: @BatCoder I know all about operator precedence. Still, to be absolutely sure, I put in extra (redundant) parentheses.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? I don't understand, It is a genuine doubt, and I can see most of you cannot figure it out either. Don't downvote a question if you too learn something from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the expressions are mathematically identical, their C++ types are different:

- The first expression has a signed number on the left side<sup>*</sup>, and an unsigned number on the right side of `<`
- The second expression converts the right side to `unsigned`, because `A.size()` is `size_t`, which is guaranteed to be unsigned.

In the second case subtracting `(num*len)` from `size()` will never produce a negative number; instead, it would produce a very large number due to an undeflow. This is what causes the difference in behavior.

<sup>*</sup> assuming that `num` and `len` are both `int`s, which is a reasonably safe assumption, given the behavior that you describe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps.